# Knockout Subscribe Not Firing After X-Editable Change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Use Case**

I am trying to set up the x-editable library around a knockout view model that can live inside of a js datatables instance. On load, it would pull down the tabular data. A user would be able to edit one field of one row and that would save automatically. I also adding some client side validation.

**Problem**

For my problem and corresponding simplified example, I took the dataTables portion out.

variable.subscribe inside the knockout viewmodel never seems to fire after x-editable changes it. I don't see any errors. I've check against multiple examples. Currently, I don't have any more clues to go off of.

**Versions**

- knockout: 3.4.0
- x-editable: 1.5.1
- valib: 2.0.0

**HTML**

```
<div id="simple-view">
    <span class="editable" data-bind="text: testA"></span>
</div>
```

**JS - Knockout View Model Portion**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    function SimpleViewModel(){
        var self = this;

        self.testA = ko.observable("Simple");

        self.testA.subscribe(function(changes){
            console.log("name changes: " + changes.length);
        });
     }

     ko.applyBindings(new SimpleViewModel(), document.getElementById('simple-view'));
})();
```

**JS - Call to X-Editable**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $(".editable").editable({
        type: 'text',
        url: function(params){
          console.log("url test: " + JSON.stringify(params));
        },
        mode: 'inline',
        anim: false,
        validate:function(value){
            var result = valib.String.match(value, /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/);
            console.log("inside validation: " + result);
            if(!result){
                return "This is a test validation response";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Problem Recap**

I can see console logs for firing the validation message and for the url parameter (which here is practically an on submit for x-editable). However, I have never seen the subscribe function work. In my non canned example code, I was also working with observable arrays. Didn't work there. Does subscribe simply not pick up changes from the browser side but instead only when the view model changes (e.g. when some code pushes data onto an observable array?)

**P.S.**
I was originally trying to get knockout-x-editable to work with knockout-validation. However, k-x-e never worked after trying every example I could find and stepping through the plugin code. Something was expected from k-x-e for the ko-validation plugin to work but it wasn't firing an error message. As such, I eventually hit a brick wall I could get past and decided to try the above approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need x-editable custom binding to enable x-editable play nice with knockoutjs.

X-editable custom binding for knockoutjs is available [here](https://github.com/brianchance/knockout-x-editable). Include this binding after knockoutjs in your page.

So you will do

```
<div id="simple-view">
    <span class="editable" data-bind="editable: testA, editableOptions:{/* your x-editable options here type, url, mode etc */}">  </span>
</div>
```

and your JS - Knockout View Model Portion

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    function SimpleViewModel(){
        var self = this;

        self.testA = ko.observable("Simple");

        self.testA.subscribe(function(changes){
            console.log("name changes: " + changes.length);
        });
     }

     ko.applyBindings(new SimpleViewModel(), document.getElementById('simple-view'));
})();
```

and then your xeditable controls will be in-sync with your observables.

Comment: I just spent the morning revisiting my old knockout-x-editable approach to see what I missed. I figured it out. For anyone who comes upon this later, when you're adding test data to your array in the foreach template, make sure you enter each item as "new datathingy()" instead of just entering raw data.

Amazing what a night's sleep can do for solving a problem.

Comment: I'm also going to mark your answer at the correct answer even if it doesn't fully explain why in that scenario subscribe wasn't firing.